# Background fixo, sem redimensionamento ao ativar teclado

Tags: java, android, background

Tenho o seguinte layout para cor, setado no `background` do `LinearLayout`:

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#7cf1db"
        android:endColor="#831f51"
        android:startColor="#038068"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Resultado:

[image: Background1]

Mas quando selecionado um EditText e o teclado acionado, a cor do fundo "sobe":

[image: Background2]

**Gostaria de deixar esse fundo fixo, sem esse "redimensionamento" ao abrir o teclado.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o teclado não modificar seu layout, utilize a seguinte *flag* no seu arquivo *Manifest.xml*:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

> adjustPan - A janela principal da atividade não é redimensionada para criar espaço para o teclado de software na tela. Em vez disso, desloca-se o conteúdo da janela automaticamente para que o foco atual nunca seja sobreposto pelo teclado e os usuários possam sempre ver o que digitam. Normalmente, esse comportamento é menos desejável que o redimensionamento, pois o usuário pode precisar fechar o teclado de software para acessar e interagir com as partes sobrepostas da janela.

Veja essa e outras *flags* para o teclado na [documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: Funcionou ! Só complementando, teria que colocar em todas `<activity>` do manifest ou existe uma forma que agregue em todas ?

Comment: Você pode por o mesmo código entre as tags `<application>`. Algo assim:   `<application android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" </application>`

Comment: No `<application>` não funcionou não.

Comment: Realmente, olhando as possíveis flags da tag `<application>`, a `windowSoftInputMode` não se encontra. Logo a maneira esperada é incluir em todas suas `<activity>`.